# Logo image not showing in any email template in Magento 1.8

Tags: javascript, html, image, magento, magento-1.7

**Issue**: In MAGENTO 1.8 v ,Logo image in any email templates is not showing in any of following :
1. Register
2. Sales
3. Orders

The image path is accurate in all cases i.e. image file is present but not showing

I have tried following solution for changing templates:

```
< use {{var logo_url}} instead {{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}
```

and its vice versa but no gain.

Even i tried to load default logo image from default magento theme but shows no reflection

This is the logo image path coming on my gmail account:

```
<img border="0" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Zj_uDGBd6hipZoFWcrUpbDPwuTrxy2bcYnCgqSTbkgdYRDPaGrtnZ3uRIWH-XLAKhRTbqsAab1F_igTdEQiGIeV3ooNNiFJ-P8_Aw-Vz8cDY6iS75vRteLtwGBJh3FhQG_-z=s0-d-e1-ft#http://example.testserver.com/skin/frontend/example/default/images/logo_email.gif">
```

Logo image is present in on this path:

```
http://example.testserver.com/skin/frontend/example/default/images/logo_email.gif
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything

Thanks

Comment: IS your site is password protected?

Comment: no..i dont think so.. btw how does this linked with password protection ?

Comment: If your site is password protected, say via an htaccess file or something similar, the email client will not be able to resolve the URL to the logo.

Comment: thanks..replacing .htaccess solves my issue